# Where do I delete objects? I'm out of scope

Tags: c++, object, stack

From what I have gathered it's imperative to delete anything that has been allocated with **new**. Having said that I feel I'm out of scope in my program to be able to access & delete those objects.

GameStateStack.h

```
#include <iostream>

class node
{
public:
    std::string gameState;
    node * nextGameState;
};

class GameStateStack
{
private:
    node * _topState;
    void Destory();

public:
    int gameStatesCount;
    void PushGameState(std::string element);
    void PopGameState();
    std::string CurrentGameState();
    GameStateStack();
    ~GameStateStack();
};

extern GameStateStack state;
```

GameStateStack.cpp

```
GameStateStack state;

GameStateStack::GameStateStack()
{
    _topState = NULL;
    gameStatesCount = 0;
}

GameStateStack::~GameStateStack()
{

}

void GameStateStack::PushGameState(std::string gameStateName)
{
    node *newTopState = new node;  // LOCAL VARIABLE
    if (_topState == NULL)
    {
      // statements
    }

    else
    {
      // statements
    }
}

void GameStateStack::PopGameState()
{
    if (_topState == NULL)
        std::cout << "Error: no gamestates available to pop";
    else
    {
        node * old = _topState;  // LOCAL VARIABLE

        // statements
    }
}

std::string GameStateStack::CurrentGameState()
{
    node *temp;  // LOCAL VARIABLE

    // statements
}

void GameStateStack::Destory()
{
    node *abc;  // I CREATED THIS VARIABLE TO ACCESS _topState variable and delete it
    delete _topState;
    delete abc->nextGameState;
    delete abc; // and then I deleted abc.
}
```

You can read the comments and see where I've posted **LOCAL VARIABLE** those I can't access in my destructor hence I cannot delete those. If I try deleting them using delete keyword in their own scope the stack that I've implemented stop working. Hence I do not know how and where to delete all these objects!

Comment: Use [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) to overcome managing dynamic memory yourself.

Comment: You are going to have to loop through your linked list and delete all the members, else use smart pointers as @πάνταῥεῖ suggests.

Comment: Why not just one of the standard containers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"Hence I do not know how and where to delete all these objects!"*

The best solution would be to get rid of calling `delete` yourself at all, but leave that to an appropriate [smart pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory), e.g.

```
class node {
public:
    std::string gameState;
    std::unique_ptr<node> nextGameState;
};
```

and all the other pointer types accordingly.

Comment: so I just need to use smart pointers and not delete at all? it will all be taken care of?

Comment: @Daqs Yes,they'll take care of the `delete`. Actually that's the recommended way how to deal with dynamic memory allocation in c++.

Answer (score 4):

`delete` acts on objects through pointer values (addresses). The pointer variables themselves are irrelevant. For example:

```
int* p1 = new int;
int* p2 = p1;
```

In this example, I've only called `new` once, and so I only have to call `delete` once, and calling it more than once would be an error. It doesn't matter whether I call it with `p1` as an argument, or `p2`, since they both point to the same object. But I should only call it on one of them, not both.

Now, how this applies to your situation. Presumably, somewhere in the code you've left out, abreviated as:

```
// statements
```

somewhere in there, you assign from your local pointer variables to member pointer variables of your class, or something else that persists outside of the function. If you didn't do this, then you have no way to access the allocated objects outside of the function, and you have a memory leak.

So assuming you did do this, it doesn't matter that the local pointers are out of scope, because you copied them to member variables which *are* in scope. So, when you're ready to delete your objects, you do it through those member pointer variables.